# GLUT batching motion callbacks on Mojave?

Tags: macos, glut, macos-mojave

I have a GLUT-based program that I'm moving from macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) to macOS Mojave (10.14.4). Yes, I know that GLUT is deprecated on both. When I compile and run the program on Mojave, GLUT seems to be batching up calls to the glutMotionFunc() callback in a way that it doesn't when it is compiled and/or run on macOS 10.13.

I've written a simple version of the program to isolate the behavior, which I've included here.  When there is no active click-and-drag motion on the GLUT window, the display callback sleeps for a "long time" (by default 300 msec), but when there is such motion detected, it sleeps for just 8 msec.

The expected behavior is that a click followed by rapid back-and-forth dragging motion will cause the program to stay in the 8 msec sleeping behavior, enabling it to sample and respond to mouse motion with low latency. When compiled *or* run on macOS 10.13.6, it behaves this way. When compiled *and* run on macOS 10.14.4, it gets a few motion callbacks in a row, but then doesn't get any after the 8 msec display callback finishes, so the next display callback takes 300 msec.  In practice, this makes the observed mouse motion very jerky.

I did enough binary chopping to isolate the change in behavior to a single byte in the binary. (I know enough about systems programming to figure out how to do this, but not enough about macOS to know just what it means.) If I take a binary compiled on macOS 10.13 and change the "sdk" field of the LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX load command to mean "10.14" rather than "10.13", it shows the jerky behavior. If I take a binary compiled on macOS 10.14 and change the "sdk" field of the LC_BUILD_VERSION load command to mean "10.13" rather than "10.14", it works again.

Is my program doing something obviously dumb that would cause this change? Or is this a Mojave bug? Also, does anyone happen to know what actually changes when I mess with the "sdk" field of the load commands?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <GLUT/glut.h>

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

typedef long long hrtime_t;

hrtime_t
gethrtime(void)
{
    struct timeval  tp;
    hrtime_t    rv;

    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    rv = ((unsigned long long)tp.tv_sec * 1000000ull + tp.tv_usec);

    return (rv);
}

static void
stamp(void)
{
    static hrtime_t then = 0;
    const hrtime_t  now = gethrtime();
    const hrtime_t  delta = (then == 0 ? 0 : now - then);

    printf("%16lld %5lld.%03lld ", now, delta / 1000, delta % 1000);
    then = now;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#define NPTS    1024

int Xs[NPTS], Ys[NPTS];
int W, R;

static void
point(int x, int y)
{
    Xs[W] = x;
    Ys[W] = y;
    W = (W + 1) % NPTS;
}

static int
line_pending(void)
{
    return (R < W && (R + 1) % NPTS < W);
}

static int
get_line(int *sxp, int *syp, int *exp, int *eyp)
{
    if (line_pending()) {
        *sxp = Xs[R];
        *syp = Ys[R];
        R = (R + 1) % NPTS;
        *exp = Xs[R];
        *eyp = Ys[R];
        return (1);
    } else {
        return (0);
    }
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

static void
keyboard_cb(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 'q') {
        exit(0);
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void
mouse_cb(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
        stamp();
        printf("[%4d, %4d]: mouse %s\n",
            x, y, (state == GLUT_DOWN) ? "down" : "up");
        point(x, y);
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void
motion_cb(int x, int y)
{
    stamp();
    printf("[%4d, %4d]: motion\n", x, y);
    point(x, y);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

static hrtime_t Delay;

static void
display_cb(void)
{
    printf("\n");
    stamp();
    if (line_pending()) {
        printf("display: found motion\n");

        while (line_pending()) {
            int sx, sy, ex, ey;

            get_line(&sx, &sy, &ex, &ey);

            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2f(sx, 512 - sy);
            glVertex2f(ex, 512 - ey);
            glEnd();
            printf("drawing [%4d %4d]-[%4d %4d]\n", sx, sy, ex, ey);
        }
        glFlush();

        stamp();
        printf("display: now sleeping 8 msec\n");
        (void) usleep(8000);
    } else {
        printf("display: no motion, doing %llu msec render\n", Delay);
        (void) usleep(1000 * Delay);
    }
    stamp();
    printf("display: done\n");
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitWindowPosition(768, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("");

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 512.0, 0.0, 512.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glFlush();

    Delay = (argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 300);

    glutDisplayFunc(display_cb);
    glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard_cb);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse_cb);
    glutMotionFunc(motion_cb);
    glutMainLoop();

    return (0);
}
```